# Django Rest with strange tags

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

The products listed have two tags, one for category and one for more fine grained description. The problem is some of the tags have ampersands and spaces etc. A choicefield seems innapropriate, does DRF handle these things gracefully with a charfield?

Edit: For instance,

```py
class Product(models.Model):
  product_department = models.CharField(max_length=75, db_index=True)
  product_detail = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True)
  id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True)

  # department could be "Clothing" for instance
  # detail could be "scarves(winter) & winter accessories"
```

So I guess the question is how to keep get requests clean in that situation without creating a complicated integer or character mapping with a choicefield.

Answer (score 0):

More details please:)

By tags do you mean fields? Can you show us the models?